# Function to return bank account balance

Tags: c++, string, function, int, cin

My function contains a string and integers but when running it I get error:

`error: could not convert 'balance' from 'int' to 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}'`

What I am trying to accomplish is to write a program that will ask if you want to 'deposit' or 'withdraw'.
Then, the program will prompt for a dollar amount (integer value). Write the 'update_balance' function to appropriately modify your balance. If the command is 'deposit', your function should add the dollar amount to the current balance; if the command is 'withdraw', your function should subtract the dollar amount from the current balance.

Return the new balance once the command has been executed.

My current code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//************************FUNCTION TO BE FIXED************************
void update_balance(string command, int dollars, int balance)
{
    if (command == "withdraw")
    {
        balance = balance - dollars;
    }
    else
    {
        balance = balance + dollars;
    }
}
//************************FUNCTION TO BE FIXED************************

int main()
{
    //the amount of money in your account
    int balance = 0;

    // Command that will tell your function what to do
    string command;
    cin >> command;

    // number of dollars you would like to deposit or withdraw
    int dollars = 0;
    cin >> dollars;

    balance = update_balance(balance, dollars, command);

    // Prints out the balance
    cout << balance << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mixed up the order the the parameters and expected return versus  / void. I mean `balance = update_balance(balance, dollars, command);` does not match `void update_balance(string command, int dollars, int balance)`.

Comment: You still did not take care of the return value. From your usage update_balance should return an int.  So instead of `void update_balance(string command, int dollars, int balance)` you need `int update_balance(string command, int dollars, int balance)` And don't forget the `return balance;`

Comment: I made the changes you directed me and it worked. I just need to figure out how to mark your help as answered

Comment: I just realized that is not an answer but a comment. My changed code now has the function as int update_balance(....) and it returns balance. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found a few errors. Here are my suggestion.
Set balance = 500 rather than 0.
Change

```
void update_balance(string command, int dollars, int balance)
```

to

```
int update_balance(int balance, int dollars, string command)
```

Add a line after the if-else loop.

```
return balance;
```

Add int balancen.

Change

```
balance = update_balance(balance, dollars, command);
```

to

```
balancen = update_balance(balance, dollars, command);
```

Comment: The last part is not needed. You can leave it as `balance`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing arguments by reference or pointers, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void update_balance(string command, int& balance, int dollars)
{
    if (command == "withdraw")
        balance -= dollars;
    else
        balance += dollars;
}

int main()
{
    //the amount of money in your account
    int balance = 0;

    // Command that will tell your function what to do
    string command;
    cin >> command;

    // number of dollars you would like to deposit or withdraw
    int dollars = 0;
    cin >> dollars;

    update_balance(command, balance, dollars);

    // Prints out the balance
    cout << balance << endl;

    return 0;
}
```